# Set the Content of the Msxml2.DOMDocument to a textarea

Tags: vbscript, textarea, domdocument

With the below code I am able to load the XML file successfully. But I want to set the total content to a textarea  How can i do that

```
Dim xmlDoc, objNodeList, plot
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.load("\ReadIT.xml")
'I want to set this xmlDoc total content to a textarea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlDoc.xml will give you the total xml content of the ReadIT.xml